# Apache Nifi failed to start web server (shutting down) during DocGenerator.generate()

Tags: apache-nifi, embedded-jetty, hortonworks-sandbox

Apache-Nifi v-1.7.1 was running fine on AWS Centos machine but now on restart it thrown following error: (below content of /nifi-app.log)

```
            org.apache.nifi:nifi-standard-nar:1.7.1 || ./work/nar/extensions/nifi-standard-nar-1.7.1.nar-unpacked
    org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.FetchSFTP
            org.apache.nifi:nifi-standard-nar:1.7.1 || ./work/nar/extensions/nifi-standard-nar-1.7.1.nar-unpacked
    org.apache.nifi.processors.azure.eventhub.ConsumeAzureEventHub
            org.apache.nifi:nifi-azure-nar:1.7.1 || ./work/nar/extensions/nifi-azure-nar-1.7.1.nar-unpacked
    === End Processor types ===
2019-01-21 10:07:15,987 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer Failed to start web server... shutting down.
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.nifi.documentation.DocGenerator.generate(DocGenerator.java:62)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:835)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:157)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:71)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:292)
2019-01-21 10:07:15,987 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Initiating shutdown of Jetty web server...
2019-01-21 10:07:15,988 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Jetty web server shutdown completed (nicely or otherwise).
```

Comment: obviously nifi failed to generate documentation for one of the nar files. probably you put new nar to the /lib folder?

Comment: or you have problems on server with unpacking nar files. check `/work/nar` folder

Comment: @daggett thanks for suggestion.. let me check. doc first.

Comment: @daggett, how to instruct jetty to not care about generating doc ?

Comment: didn't worked..

Comment: Something wrong  with unpacking nars. Check for any warnings in log files like `Unable to load NAR library...`. Set `DEBUG` level for `org.apache.nifi` in `logback.xml`, clean the logs and restart the server and look for nar that fails to extract...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo chown -R nifi:nifi /opt/nifi/
sudo service nifi start
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this issue when the folders pointed to by nifi.nar.library.directory.* was inaccessible, e.g. the Symbolic links were no longer valid due to file system changes.

Fixed the links and the server came up.

Comment: How did you fix them?

Comment: As stated, referenced location was inaccessible, be it permissions or broken links. Correct permissions or links and service started fine. Note I had custom processors in shared HA folder which became unavailable when admins modified autofs.